# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\tan^n(x)}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

> Compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\tan^n(x)}\,dx$$

I tried to do a variable change $\tan x=t$ and arrived at another integral but I haven't solved it yet.

Comment: Consider stating the actual question in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\tan^n(x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{1+\tan^n(x)}\,dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\tan^n(x)}\,dx$$in the interval $(0,{\pi\over 4})$ the integrand tends to $1$ **but not uniformly** and in $({\pi/4},\pi/3)$ the integrand tends to $0$ **also not uniformly but pointwise**, therefore$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\tan^n(x)}\,dx={\pi\over 4}$$Here is a sketch of the function for some values of $n$:[image]

Comment: Your "therefore" needs further proof. The DCT would finish it off quickly, but with more elementary means it'll take a bit of work.